# How to Ensure App-Wide Frequency Cap Applies Across Different Ad Formats in AdMob Without Affecting Show Rate?

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm integrating AdMob into my Android application, using both interstitial and reward ads. I'm trying to implement the app-wide frequency cap feature that AdMob now provides. However, I'm having difficulty applying this setting consistently across multiple ad formats.

Specifically, once an ad is shown and the frequency cap is reached, other ads that have already been loaded can still be displayed. This happens even though the cap should apply across all ad formats in the app.

My current solution is to clear all loaded ads after an ad of any format is shown. However, I'm concerned that this will significantly decrease the show rate and potentially impact my ad revenue.

My question is:

How can I ensure the app-wide frequency cap is respected across all loaded ad formats without significantly affecting the show rate?

Is there a better approach to enforcing the cap across all loaded ads that won't potentially lower my revenue?

I would appreciate any insights or alternative solutions that can help solve this issue. Thank you!